# Problems with sending

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So, my server has channels for each user, and the name of the channel is their user id.

The way I want it to work is;

When a user DMs the bot with any message, the bot looks for that channel (the channel that's named as their user id) in the server and sends the content of the message it receieved in DMs, but I keep getting an error:

```js
Cannot read property "send" of undefined
```

Here is my code

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
        if (message.author.bot) return;

        var guild = client.guilds.cache.get("840120593311334410");

        const cha = message.author.id;
        var hsa = await guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.name === cha);
        hsa.send("test");
    }
});
```

Comment: You get the error because you are using `await` with `guild.channels.cache.find`. `Collection.find` is a synchronous method. Remove the `await`.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.

Comment: Since channels are mapped by their ID, you could simply do `var hsa = guild.channels.cache.get(cha) `

Comment: The thing is I'm not looking for the channel by the channel id, but by the id of the message author, because that's how the channels are named.

Comment: Are you sure the channel exists? When do you create them? Does the bot have permissions to see it?

Comment: Yes, the channel exists and yes the bot has access to both send messages and see it.

Comment: Can you just check the channel name, digit for digit, so that it's the exact same as the user's ID? Sometimes there is integer overflow since IDs are really long.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of problems I have for you:

1. The bot doesn’t have the permissions to see the channel, or the channel doesn’t exist. (You said otherwise in comments however)
2. You do not have the channel in the cache -
   The code you use relies on cache which means you have to make sure you have the channels cached. Use a simple `GuildChannelManager.fetch()` to cache all the channels.

```js
        var guild = client.guilds.cache.get("840120593311334410");

        const cha = message.author.id;
        await guild.channels.fetch(); //ONLY NEW LINE
        var hsa = await guild.channels.cache.find((ch) => ch.name === cha);
        hsa.send("test");
```